# How to enable tooltip on disabled button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a disabled button and i want it to show a tooltip but change it when i enable it again. How do i get this to work  i can only use HTML, javascript and css.
This is the button

```html
<div class="right-item"><button class="button ripple" id="print" onclick="printDiv('qr-code')" disabled="disabled">Drucken</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with tooltip? These are typically triggered and created via js, but I don't see any JS in your post. Or do you mean the `title` attribute (normally, that's not what people mean with tooltip)?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/tooltip/how-to/show-tooltip-on-disabled-elements-and-disable-tooltip/

Comment: @cloned in my post you see only the button and i need to add the tooltip with js

Comment: Then add it? Or do you expect us to code it for you?

Comment: I dont expect anything but i dont know how to add a tooltip on a disabled button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use title

```js
function toggle() {
  var button = document.getElementById('button');
  if (button.disabled) {
    button.disabled = false;
    button.setAttribute('title', 'Enabled title');
  } else {
    button.disabled = true;
    button.setAttribute('title', 'Disabled title');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle enable/disable</button>
<button disabled title="Enabled title" id="button">Hover on me</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<button disabled title="Hello">Hover on me</button>`

This code will show same tool tip for both disabled or enabled button. Have a function which checks the status of button and apply the title value based on it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Javascript when you enable button.

In jQuery:

```
$('#yourElementId').attr('title', 'your new title');
```

In Javascript:

```
var myBtn= document.getElementById("yourElementId");
myBtn.setAttribute('title','mytitle');
```